# How can I set file permissions for new files in Maildir?

Tags: permissions, postfix, acl, dovecot, thunderbird

So I run debian 10 through VMbox on win10. I am setting up an email server right now and the things that won't let me turn in this quest is that I can't receive mail from the internet though I can send it. The mail is stored in /var/mail/Maildir and subfolders like new, cur, tmp and when an email drops in, this file doesn't have the right permissions and I can't read it through thunderbird until I manually set the rights. All the new letters have -rw-------+ permissions. What can I do to make all new letters have 755 rights automatically? I really need help, I am still new to this and not being able to figure it out drives me mad.

Things I've tried:

```
chown -R :mail /var/mail/Maildir
chmod -R 755 /var/mail/Maildir
```

and

```
setfacl -R -m "group:mail:rwX" $dir                # Sets the effective ACL.
setfacl -R -d -m "group:mail:rwX" $dir             # Sets the inheritable ACL.
```

But still I can't get the permissions right. I use passwd database as a driver so all the users are local debian users like root or alex united by "mail" group.

In logs I have this:

```
Jul 21 21:42:15 mail dovecot: imap(alex)<2920><4nRq+/eqcMl/AAAB>: Error: Mailbox INBOX: open(/var/mail/Maildir/cur/1595355455.Vfe04Idf939M195657.mail.magrega.ru.eu.org:2,) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(alex) egid=1004(alex) missing +r perm: /var/mail/Maildir/cur/1595355455.Vfe04Idf939M195657.mail.magrega.ru.eu.org:2,)
Jul 21 21:42:15 mail dovecot: imap(alex)<2920><4nRq+/eqcMl/AAAB>: FETCH failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2020-07-21 21:42:15] in=275 out=1023 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

I enter `chmod g+r var/mail/Maildir/cur/` and everything starts working until I get a new mail which has only `-rw------+` permissions.

Comment: You aren't showing answerers the ACL entries.  How do you expect them to tell you what is going on with your access controls if you don't even show them what they are on the files and directories concerned?  They cannot reach around the planet into your computer to find out for themselves.  This sort of stuff _must_ be explicitly in a question.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. I am new to this and I didn't know that ACL had any sort of entries. I thought of it more like chown\chmod commands which you just set in console.

Comment: Where can I find those entries?